# How to use Pooled Spring beans instead of Singleton ones?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, ejb

For efficiency reasons, I am interested in limiting the number of threads that simultaneously uses the beans of the Spring application context (I don't want an **unlimited** number of threads proccessing in my **limited** memory).

I have found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.0/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool) (spring documentation) a way to achieve this by pooling the beans in a EJB style, by doing the following:

- Declare the target bean as scope "prototype".
- Declare a Pool provider that will deliver a limited number of pooled "target" instances.
- Declare a "ProxyFactoryBean" which function is not clear to me.

Here is the declaration of this beans:

```
<bean id="businessObjectTarget" class="com.mycompany.MyBusinessObject" 
    scope="prototype">
  ... properties omitted
</bean>

<bean id="poolTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="businessObjectTarget"/>
  <property name="maxSize" value="25"/>
</bean>

<bean id="businessObject" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetSource" ref="poolTargetSource"/>
  <property name="interceptorNames" value="myInterceptor"/>
</bean>
```

My problem is that when I will declare another bean to use pooled instances of the "businessObjectTarget", how should I do it? I mean, when i try to do something like this:

```
<bean id="clientBean" class="com.mycompany.ClientOfTheBusinessObject">
  <property name="businessObject" ref="WHAT TO PUT HERE???"/>
</bean>
```

What should be the value of the "ref" ??

Comment: If you mean "businessObjectTarget" then I would not be using any pooling, but a single instance of "MyBusinessObject".
If you mean "businessObject", ther is not any bean declared with that name.

Comment: <bean id="businessObject" class="..PFB"> ?

Comment: @abalogh I'm sorry, i don't understand, your comments are not very verbose. You are suggesting to declare a bean businessObject of type "ProxyFactoryBean"? this is already done in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use properties to get instances of prototypes.
One option is to use the lookup methods (see [chapter 3.3.7.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html))
Another option to get your bean in code: make your `com.mycompany.ClientOfTheBusinessObject` to implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface and then call `context.getBean("clientBean")`

Comment: Do you mean that I can only use pooled beans if I retrieve them programmatically from the application context, but I cannot use an "injected pooled dependency"??

Comment: Any bean with prototype scope (not only pooled beans) cannot be injected in a "normal way", since the "normal way" will occur only once. I suggest you read the chapter 3.3 in my answer, it explains it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks. I know that if you inject a prototype in the "normal way" it will occur only once. What i expect from Spring in the pooled case is that throught a proxy it manages to invoke a pooled instance, blocking the thread if no instances are available. It is technically possible the same way it intercepts other calls to manage transactionality and so on... But it seems that Spring does not support this feature (EJB does).

Comment: @edutesoy, I think ProxyFactoryBean in combination with CommonsPoolTargetSource does exactly what you intend. From the docs: "Using a pooling target source provides a similar programming model to stateless session EJBs, in which a pool of identical instances is maintained, with method invocations going to free objects in the pool."

Answer (score 1):

Please note the name of the third bean in the spring example:-"businessObject"

It means this the bean from where you are supposed to access the common pool.

For your case if you need your own client bean you may have it as follows.
But in such a case businessObject is not required.:-

```
<bean id="businessObjectTarget" class="com.mycompany.MyBusinessObject" 
    scope="prototype">

  ... properties omitted
</bean>

<bean id="poolTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="businessObjectTarget"/>
  <property name="maxSize" value="25"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientBean" class="com.mycompany.ClientOfTheBusinessObject">
 <property name="poolTargetSource" ref="poolTargetSource"/>
</bean>


Java classes:-
public class ClientOfTheBusinessObject{
     CommonsPoolTargetSource poolTargetSource;
//<getter and setter for poolTargeTSource>
  public void methodToAccessCommonPool(){
     //The following line gets the object from the pool.If there is nothing left in the pool then the thread will be blocked.(The blocking can be replaced with an exception by changing the properties of the CommonsPoolTargetSource bean)
     MyBusinessObject mbo = (MyBusinessObject)poolTargetSource.getTarget();
     //Do whatever you want to do with mbo
     //the following line puts the object back to the pool
     poolTargetSource.releaseTarget(mbo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can limit the number of simultaneous threads in a less convoluted way. Did you look at the Java Concurrency API, specifically at the Executors.newFixedThreadPool() ?

Answer (score 0):

i used java-configuration to construct a proxy over the interface that handles pooling using apache commons-pool to achieve invocation-level-pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Annotations based configuration:

1. I did create my `BusinessObject` class as a POJO and annotate it this way:

   ```
   @Component("businessObject")
   @Scope("prototype")
   public class BusinessObject { ... }
   ```

   I gave it a specific name and did mark it as *prototype* so that Spring doesn't create a singleton instance for it; every time the bean is required, Spring would create a new instance.
2. In my `@Configuration` class (or in the `@SpringBootApplication` class, if using Spring Boot) I created a `CommonsPool2TargetSource` instance to hold `BusinessObject` instances:

   ```
   @Bean
   public CommonsPool2TargetSource pooledTargetSource() {
       final CommonsPool2TargetSource commonsPoolTargetSource = new CommonsPool2TargetSource();
       commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetBeanName("businessObject");
       commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetClass(BusinessObject.class);
       commonsPoolTargetSource.setMaxSize(maxPoolSize);
       return commonsPoolTargetSource;
   }
   ```

   Here I'm indicating that the pool will hold `BusinessObject` instances. Notice that my `maxPoolSize=?` value is set with the max number of `BusinessObject` instances I want to hold in the pool.
3. Finally, I did access my pooled instances this way:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private CommonsPool2TargetSource pooledTargetSource;

   void someMethod() {
       // First I retrieve one pooled BusinessObject instance
       BusinessObject businessObject = (BusinessObject)pooledTargetSource.getTarget();

       try {
           // Second, I do some logic using the BusinessObject instance gotten
       } catch (SomePossibleException e) {
           // Catch and handle any potential error, if any
       } finally {

           // Finally, after executing my business logic
           // I release the BusinessObject instance so that it can be reused
           pooledTargetSource.releaseTarget(businessObject);
       }
   }
   ```

   It is very important to always make sure to release the `BusinessObject` *borrowed* from the pool, without mattering if the business logic did finish successfully or with error. Otherwise the pool could get empty with all the instances being borrowed and never released and any further requests for instances will block forever.