# How do I actually use a Spring pooled object?

Tags: java, spring, pool

I am working through an example of spring pooling described here.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.0/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool

I have read through a very similar question here, but still don't have an answer.

[How to use Pooled Spring beans instead of Singleton ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493583/how-to-use-pooled-spring-beans-instead-of-singleton-ones)

Assuming I have the following beans defined in my SpringConfig file, how do I actually use the pooled objects?

```
<bean id="businessObjectTarget" class="com.mycompany.MyBusinessObject" scope="prototype">
    ... properties omitted
</bean>

<bean id="poolTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="businessObjectTarget"/>
  <property name="maxSize" value="25"/>
</bean>

<bean id="businessObject" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetSource" ref="poolTargetSource"/>
</bean>
```

I am doing something like this but I have no idea how to tell if it working.

```
@Resource(name = "businessObject")
private MyBusinessObject businessObject;
...
method() {
   ...
   businessObject.method();
   ...
}
```

How am I actually supposed to use the pooled object?

Thanks.

PS - I am even less sure of it working now.  I made the following change and submitted two threads.  The first one worked, the second one got an error indicative of simultaneous use:

```
<bean id="poolTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="businessObjectTarget" />
    <property name="maxSize" value="1" />
    <property name="whenExhaustedActionName" value="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_FAIL" />
</bean>
```

I am very skeptical.

Comment: Like you are doing now. For your code there is no difference in using a pooled object or a regular object (as it should be).

Comment: I am still confused.  The resource annotation cannot be used on method level variables so the pooled object needs to be at the class level.  Since the owning object is itself a singleton, the businessObject variable will be accessed by many threads at once.  This is still an issue - no?

Comment: No it isn't. You get a proxy for the `MyBusinessObject` which handles the pooling.