# How to create a spring bean with specific number of maximum instances

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thread-safety

I need to create a spring prototype bean in a server with limited RAM.
One option is to use a spring bean which is a mix of Singleton and Prototype scopes, where i can specify maximum number of instances and threads.

Is there any way in Spring to create multi instance beans? 
If not how to we avoid out of memory errors when using spring prototype beans.

Comment: Can you describe your general goal please? Life cycle of the prototypes (time to clear, time to create and so on)?

Comment: seems like duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493583/how-to-use-pooled-spring-beans-instead-of-singleton-ones?rq=1

Comment: Its not duplicate, this is a question about prototype bean's memory handling

Comment: Hi @Sergii the questions is to know memory impact of using prototype beans and from infrastructure management point of view, how do we make sure that at later point of time the application is not suddenly stopped with out of memory errors

Comment: @amitmah I try clarify if is ok for you to create singleton, and manage all situations using singleton, may be with additional existing solutions. It would be good if you share this information... it's not a big secret i guess.

Comment: Thanks @Sergii, The problem I have in using singleton is that there are class level member data available and it can not be shared with other threads. One option is to use synchronization with Singleton but that makes application very unresponsive.

Comment: Can i check problem part example please?

Comment: Sure Here is the example 

#Repository
Class ABCService {
#Autowired
ABCUtility utility;
public String jsonRestServiceMethod(){
//..
}
}


#Repository
public class ABCUtility {

public String[] dataFromDB;

public Synchronized String getDetailsFromDB(String[] vars){
//...
}
public Synchronized String performMoreActions(String a, String b){
//..
}
}

Converted AtTheRate to #

Comment: I need to change ABCUtility to prototype bean but still use 512 MB memory of server

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use spring for your purposes I would suggest using ***factory bean***.

Your context:

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="tool" class="com.example.ToolFactory"/>
</beans>
```

An example of a factory bean:

```
public class ToolFactory implements FactoryBean<Tool> {
    private AtomicInteger currentId = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public Tool getObject() throws Exception {
        return new Tool(currentId.incrementAndGet());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() { return Tool.class; }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() { return false; }
}

public class Tool {
    private final int id;
    public Tool(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
}
```

In `Toolfactory.getObject()`  you can implement any logic you wish. 
You can create a Pool of beans inside this factory. 
Or you could throw an exception when bean count limit is reached.

[How to use the Spring FactoryBean?](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean)
[What's a FactoryBean?](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)